# Cannot launch .desktop files (opens with Text Editor instead)

Tags: .desktop

For some reason, I cannot launch `.desktop` files. When I double-click the file, it opens the Text Editor. The desktop file has "Allow executing file as program" turned on (`-rwx`). In the tab "Open with", the Text Editor is the default application. Clicking reset in that tab changes it to the Text Editor, so it basically does nothing.

Any way to solve this?

Answer (score 20):

Basically, I found that the Files/Nautilus application does not allow executing `.desktop` files anymore. Instead there are 2 options we can do.

1. Enable 'Desktop icons' using GNOME Tweaks and create the `.desktop` file inside the Desktop folder. Then it will appear on the desktop (without its icon). Then right click on the desktop icon and choose "Allow launching" and the icon will appear and it will be executable.
2. Add the `.desktop` file inside the `~/.local/share/applications` and then it will appear in the App launcher, so you can add it to the Dock (add to favorites) and copy to the Desktop folder to add to Desktop.

Comment: Is there a CLI way for "Allow Launching"?

Comment: "Allow launching" is not an option on 20.04.

Comment: Sometimes it requires a logout and login for the desktop files in the user's application folder to appear in the app launcher or for the _Allow launching_ option to appear in the desktop icon's context menu. I'm using Ubuntu 20.10 Beta with Gnome 3.38, not sure if it's some bug or something else. However, your answer worked for me, upvoted!

Comment: Man, they've really hobbled Nautilus...

Comment: For those interested a CLI way of solving it has been found:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1314919/creating-a-program-shortcut-on-the-desktop-entirely-from-the-terminal-in-ubuntu
...hope it helps you like it did for me.