# Ubuntu 20.04/21.10: how to create an app shortcut to a bash file?

Tags: bash, shortcuts, 21.10, appmenu, favorites

i have this bash script: test.sh that i would like to be able to find in my apps and/or as a favorite in my dock.

since i've never done that i relied on:
[Execute sh script from *.desktop file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/398666/execute-sh-script-from-desktop-file)

i then created a file: test.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=TEST
Comment=bash copy/resize
Exec=bash ~/mybash/test.sh
NoDisplay=False
Terminal=False
Type=Application
Icon=~/usr/share/pixmaps/copy-resize.png
Categories=Accessories;
```

set permission to execute, and created `/usr/share/applications`, `/usr/share/pixmaps` and `/mybash` in my home directory to start with.
I could right click it and run as application, but it was not visible in settings>applications

dragging it to the desktop didn't help, so found:
[Cannot launch .desktop files (opens with Text Editor instead)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187934/cannot-launch-desktop-files-opens-with-text-editor-instead)

since i did not know how to find the /.local folder i decided to copy the file:

```
sudo cp ~/usr/share/applications/test.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
```

It now can be found under settings>applications alas it is listed without the icon but  i cannot find it under apps.
If i search in the app view (9 dots) i find the `/.local/share/applications/test.desktop` listed as a text file and right clicking does not give me the option to set it to favorites and left it opens in geany (as it was made with that app)

if i try in a terminal:

```
bash ~/.local/share/applications/test.desktop
```

it starts the sh script, output in terminal:

```
/home/maarten/.local/share/applications/test.desktop: 1: [Desktop: not found
/home/maarten/.local/share/applications/test.desktop: 3: Cam: not found
starting gui...
```

and that does it's job, in the dock I see the icon I choose and a dot that it's active and the gui opens.
so except for the icon location in settings>applications this part works.
But double clicking still leads to the text editor.
If placed on the desktop i can set 'allow launching' changing the file icon to a text document, but then double click does nothing.

the big question is Who can fill me in on what i missed in making this work?

At this moment i've copied test.desktop to:

```
(home)/test.desktop, (with/without allow launching)
/Desktop/test.desktop, 
/.local/share/applications/test.desktop and 
/usr/share/applications/test.desktop.
```

on all placed i can use a rightclick and choose to run as program, but nowhere does a double click lead to opening the file.

Comment: You said: "if i try in a terminal: bash ~/.local/share/applications/test.desktop, 
it starts the sh script and that does it's job. I do not believe that that worked with the file you provided. Please check and correct the information.

Comment: i just tried again and it might not be perfect:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Quick-Fix

**Try the steps below**

1. Change your .desktop file by replacing `~/some/path/file.ext` to `/home/<username>/some/path/file.ext`
2. You can also set `Terminal=True` to open a terminal when running the .desktop shortcut.

   Your .desktop file should look like this:

   ```bsh
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=TEST
   Comment=bash copy/resize
   Exec=bash /home/<your-username>/mybash/test.sh
   NoDisplay=False
   Terminal=True
   Type=Application
   Icon=/usr/local/share/pixmaps/copy-resize.png
   Categories=Accessories;
   ```

### Expected Behavior w/ Screenshots

- When viewing `.desktop` files in a File browser like Nautilus, the files will appear like typical text files or potentially with gear symbols on them
  [image]
- When double-clicking on a `.desktop` file the default file action set for that mime-type in xdg-settings will be applied, in this case the .desktop file will open in your default text-editor
  [image]
   
  you can check your xdg-mime settings like this:
  [image]

  As you can see, my default is GNOME Builder too

- I've been showing the above using the JetBrains CLion IDE .desktop file, now let me show you how to properly utilize the .desktop file.

  1. first access your application menu with `Super/Win` key on your keyboard, or by clicking on the 3x3 grid icon on your taskbar *[**note**: this can differ depending on your desktop environment and your configuration]*
     [image]
  2. start typing your application name; in your case <kbd>TEST</kbd> but in my example <kbd>CLion</kbd>
     [image]

### Info

1. it's already been pointed out that using the `~` shortcut doesn't work inside a <kbd>Unity Launcher</kbd> .desktop file

   which is why you need to specify the full path to your script and its icon file
2. you should use either `/home/<username>/.local/share/applications/` for just your user account to see the entry
   or `/usr/local/share/applications/` for all users of the machine to see the entry
3. you don't need a `$HOME/usr/` folder, `$HOME/.local/` is probably what you were thinking of
4. refer [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles#:%7E:text=Unity%20Launchers%20are%20actually%20files,access%20from%20the%20Unity%20Launcher.) for more details about how to properly setup a .desktop launcher file

### References

[Unity Launcher Specification](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles#:%7E:text=Unity%20Launchers%20are%20actually%20files,access%20from%20the%20Unity%20Launcher.)
[Ubuntu-desktop command manual](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/desktop-file-edit.1.html)

Comment: Thanks, that at least got rid of the '~' but still, a double click opens the file in the editor. only right click and 'run as program' or via terminal with bash

Comment: yes thank you, after doing that, when placed on the desktop and 'allow launching' is activated it will double click, maybe you can add that to your answer

Comment: if the program is active, i have the icon in my dock, but on the desktop it looks like a text file, do you know the solution for that one too?

Comment: the double click opening in a text editor is standard expected behavior. these files are meant to show up in your `Application` menu when you click on your keyboards `Super / Win` key or when you search for an application in your `Activities Overview`

Comment: typically it showing as a text file means you need to set the `.desktop` file's executable bit using `chmod +x filename.desktop`. Or right-clicking with your mouse and setting permissions through the GUI.

Comment: thanks William, i grasp it much better now, will write it out for the next time this comes up....and changed the icon via the gui, so that's settled too :)

Comment: You're welcome, @user74341. Not to force your hand but if you up-vote my answer that will help give me more reputation points and allow me to do more on this forum. If you don't think my answer deserves and up-vote, then don't feel obligated to provide one.

Comment: well, you went out of your way after i have it working, so i'll upvote you..the least i can do.....although not working as i expected, i was thinking it would end up in that 3x3 grid as a launchable application too, but there it are just editor launches again without the proper icon as i see in your screenprint.

Comment: got it! thanks..all works as expected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135417/discussion-between-william-smyth-and-user74341).

Comment: yesterday there was a moment that i thought both my scripts were working, i have one that starts a gui and one that stayes in the terminal. since these changes i do not see the terminal window before the gui starts and the non-gui version does not open a terminal window. If i right click and choose 'run as program' it will however still open a terminal (with the errors seen in the first post)

Comment: solved with adding gnome-terminal -e

Answer (score 0):

It works if the desktop file is located in the home folder. The options 'set to favorites' appears.

There is also useful application called 'menulibre'.

Comment: i copied test.desktop to the home folder, no option set to favorites appears.
installed menulibre, but am unsure what to do with it.

Comment: First sentence definitely is a wrong answer. Suggestion on second line might not work here if the desktop file is already valid to start with. Did you test anything?

Comment: if i open a winndow and go to home i see desktop, downloads, etc at the end there is one file: test.desktop, if i right click that i see: open with, run as program, cut, copy, move to, copy to, move to trash, rename, compress, send to, star, properties...where can i find set to favorites?

Comment: and i tested what you see at the beginning and some more, but i do not really know what i'm doing (wrong) so it's hard to come up with a test.