# Why can't I run a .desktop file copied from Ubuntu/usr/share/application to desktop when I copy or move it to a folder?

Tags: gparted

GParted runs ok when copied to desktop, but when I copy or move it to a folder a double click results in a text file with entries like "Name(de)=GParted"

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187934/cannot-launch-desktop-files-opens-with-text-editor-instead

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot launch .desktop files (opens with Text Editor instead)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187934/cannot-launch-desktop-files-opens-with-text-editor-instead)